# Unable to connect to redis on amazon (same VPC different subnets)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to set up a Redis cluster using amazon's ElasticCache
I have a VPC with the following CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16.

Which has five subnets:
2 private - 10.0.3.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24

3 public - 10.0.0.0/24 10.0.2.0/24 10.0.4.0/24

After the creation of the Redis cluster I wasn't able to connect using the hostname that was provided in the console.
I am 100% sure I have something configured wrong in terms of network (I am not a network expert)

My security group enabled access to port 6379 from 0.0.0.0/0
and the server that I am trying to connect from is in the same VPC but not in the same subnets as the Redis cluster.
I want to connect from the servers that are in the Public subnets to the Redis which is in the private subnets

**Edit 1:**

I was able to connect using `telnet` to the hostname and port.
When I use the `redis-cli` command I am not getting a response

Comment: Any error response from redis-cli?  What is the full command you're using.  If telnet to the port works, it's probably not a networking issue

Comment: turns out that because of the redis AUTH that was enabled it wasn't able to connect with the redis-cli. found something on github

Comment: Feel free to add that solution to as an answer to this question! Your rep is low enough it'll take a couple days, but you can then Accept the answer and everyone will know there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that because of the redis AUTH that was enabled it wasn't able to connect with the redis-cli. found something on github